# Custom post type meta box empty after save

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I'm trying to make a meta box to include a date picker but my initial attempt to have the textbox data seems to fail as each time its either posted or saved again the text disapears

```
    <?
/*
Plugin Name: Mobilisation
Plugin URI: http://www.seriadesign.com
Description: Plugin servant a gerer la mobilisation
Version: 0.01
Author: Christophe Rudyj
Author URI: http://www.seriadesign.com
License: Seria-CSN
*/
 // Create out post type
    add_action( 'init', 'csn_mob_register' );
    function csn_mob_register() {
    $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Mobilisations', 'mob' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Mobilisation', 'mob' ),
    'add_new' => _x( 'Ajouter', 'mob' ),
    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Ajouter une Mobilisation', 'mob' ),
    'edit_item' => _x( 'Editer une Mobilisation', 'mob' ),
    'new_item' => _x( 'Ajouter une Mobilisation', 'mob' ),
    'view_item' => _x( 'Voir une Mobilisation', 'mob' ),
    'search_items' => _x( 'Rechercher une Mobilisations', 'mob' ),
    'not_found' => _x( 'Aucune mobilisations trouvée', 'mob' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Aucune mobilisations trouvée dans la Corbeille', 'mob' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Mobilisation:', 'mob' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'Mobilisations', 'mob' ),
    );
    $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post'
    );
            register_post_type( 'mob', $args );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'mob' );
    } 

function important_category( $id, $post ) {
if ( 'mob' === get_post_type( $id ) ) {
 $category   = get_term_by( 'slug', 'important', 'category' );
 $categories = wp_get_object_terms( $id, 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
 if ( !in_array( $category->term_id, $categories ) ) {
  wp_set_object_terms( $id, ( int ) $category->term_id, 'category', true );
 }
}
} add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'important_category' );

/* meta box */
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'mob_date_add');
function mob_date_add() {

    add_meta_box( 'mob_datebox','Date de Fin', 'mob_dateshow', 'mob','side', 'default' );
}

function mob_dateshow() {
global $post;  
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );  
    $text = isset( $values['mob_datetext'] ) ? $values['mob_datetext'] : '';  
   wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>  
    <label for="mob_datetext">Date de fin</label>  
    <input type="text" name="mob_datetext" id="mob_datetext"  value="<?php echo $text; ?>" />   
    <?
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'mob_datebox_save', 1, 2);  
function mob_datebox_save( $post, $post_id )  
{  
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save  
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return; 

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail 
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return; 

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail  
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;  
}  


// now we can actually save the data  
    $allowed = array(   
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags  
            'href' => array() // and those anchors can only have href attribute  
        )  
    );  

    // Make sure your data is set before trying to save it  
    if( isset( $_POST['mob_datetext'] ) )  
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mob_datetext', wp_kses( $_POST['mob_datetext'], $allowed ) );  




?>
```

Comment: your `mob_datebox_save` function closes before the post meta is saved.

Comment: Are you trying to save it in array?

Answer (score 1):

As @Milo Said. Your function is ended early. Try this for `save_post` action.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'mob_datebox_save', 1, 2);  
function mob_datebox_save( $post, $post_id )  
{  
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save  
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return; 

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail 
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return; 

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail  
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;  



// now we can actually save the data  
    $allowed = array(   
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags  
            'href' => array() // and those anchors can only have href attribute  
        )  
    );  

    // Make sure your data is set before trying to save it  
    if( isset( $_POST['mob_datetext'] ) )  
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mob_datetext', wp_kses( $_POST['mob_datetext'], $allowed ) );  

}
```

Also try to use **`<?php`** instead of **`<?`** for PHP opening.